# ASP.NET docker-compose app not coming up on assigned PORT

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

working my way through tutorials on dockerized the API WeatherForecast web template from ASP.NET core:

1. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-aspnet-core
2. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/docker-compose

I had to start from here, because I wasn't getting a new image to build using the tutorial here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/aspnet-mssql-compose/

"1" works, which is great. However, "2" will not work on the `localhost:5000/WeatherForecast`  port as advertised, and I'm having some trouble debugging why after many reviews of the available docs.

I should make a note that in creating the templated app from the command line, I did choose the --no-https option.

I then used docker ps  to bring up the PORTS . The web app is using `5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32779->80/tcp` . When I substitute `5000`  for `32779` , I get the API string returned instead!
I know I'm missing something within docker-compose  and could use some extra eyes on it. Thank you!

EDIT: For reference, the files below were generated by my VSCode editor.
1. I ran dotnet new webapi --no-https
2. I then brought up the VSCode "command pallete" and ran `Docker: Add Dockerfiles to Workspace` and selected 'yes' for the inclusion of docker-compose.yml file and Linux. I also choose to use port `5000`. I use Fedora 30.
4. I run `dotnet build` from the project root in the terminal.
5. If I run from `docker` commands and make the ports explicit it will work as advertised, but if I run `docker-compose -f <yml-file> up -d- --build`, it will not.

I just re-read this and find it annoying that I'm stuck within VSCode to fix the issue (according to the docs)

> By default Docker will assign a randomly chosen host port to a port exposed by a container (the container port). In this case the exposed (container) port is 5000, but it will be exposed on the host via a random port, such as 32737.
>
> You can use specific port on the host by changing the Docker run options used by docker-run: debug task (defined in .vscode/tasks.json file). For example, if you want to use the same port (5000) to expose the service, the docker-run: debug task definition would look like this:

a. `Dockerfile`

```
    # Please refer https://aka.ms/HTTPSinContainer on how to setup an 
    https developer certificate for your ASP .NET Core service.
    version: '3.4'

    services:
      aspdotnetdocker2:
        image: aspdotnetdocker2
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - 5000
```

b. `docker-compose.yml`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["aspdotnet_docker2.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./aspdotnet_docker2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "aspdotnet_docker2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "aspdotnet_docker2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspdotnet_docker2.dll"]
```

Comment: What does your *docker-compose.yml* look like?

Comment: ```
# Please refer https://aka.ms/HTTPSinContainer on how to setup an https developer certificate for your ASP .NET Core service.
version: '3.4'

services:
  aspdotnetdocker2:
    image: aspdotnetdocker2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000
```

Comment: I apologize in advance, still learning how to use the code formatting on the forum.

Comment: It would be easier if you edit your question and post the yml file in question where you could use code format. I'd be particularly interested in the `ports` setup.

Comment: I just updated the post!

Comment: This post has an answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62482720/does-docker-compose-create-port-mappings-automatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports):

> **SHORT SYNTAX**
>
> Either specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER), or just the container port (an **ephemeral host port** is chosen).

So try:

```
ports:
  - "5000:<port in ASPNETCORE_URLS>"

  # e.g.
  # - "5000:80"
  # - "44388:443"
```

Comment: Tried it, but I'm still not bringing up the expected JSON string.

Comment: Maybe the `Expose:` tag will work? EDIT: nevermind, Dockerfile already exposes port `5000`.

Comment: I assume you follow the referenced MS docs, so what is the value of `ASPNETCORE_URLS` in your yml file? Your application shall run on the port specified, then you need to expose the port correctly in your yml file, using "5000:<port in ASPNETCORE_URLS>".

Comment: Alright, works now. I thought I had done that originally, so thank you for the reminder. Go figure it was something fairly simple that I was doing that was throwing everything else off. Thanks for your help.